# envivo mini diasscanner driver workaround

Tags: drivers, hardware, scanner

Hi I have attached my envivo mini diasscanner to a usb port.
Lsusb finds it as: Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0ac8:3370 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. Traveler TV 6500 SF Dia-scanner.
Have anybody got this device to work in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this device working on linux mint. I downloaded and installed "Cheese" camera via our software manager, and it worked straight off. Prior to that it hadn't even been detected.

Kudos to the guy who pointed out that it is really a camera (on a German Mint forum (in English)). Everything Ubuntu works on Mint. I hope vice versa is true

Comment: Great it works, just had to change resolution, and reboot!
Even the button on top works, counting down and taking a picture. It works in Studio too, kudos to you both :-)